# Calling model from view error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, mvc, fix-my-code

I am just starting with Joomla component development and MVC in general. Im also not incredibly strong in PHP but I am trying to build a component that gets json and displays it as a jQuery accordion list.

I started by creating a PHP script that does just that and it works fine.

Now Im on the component part and the mvc is tripping me up. I adapted the hello world component in the docs tutorial found here: http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/3.1/Introduction

But when I install the component and go to my component I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function getProject() in /[path to joomla]/components/com_insightly/views/insightly/view.html.php on line 23
```

So my view cant use a function I defined in my model. I must be missing something because I thought the controller assigned the model to the view auto-magically.

Here is some source, (sorry im not indenting 8 spaces on each line manually)

site\models\insightly.php

```
// import Joomla modelitem library
jimport('joomla.application.component.modelitem');


class InsightlyModelInsightly extends JModelItem
{

public function getProject($user_id)
{

    $project_url = 'https://api.insight.ly/v2/projects/'.$user_id;
    $project = array();
    $html_tag = null;
    $html_class = null;
    $html_id = null;

    $curl = curl_init($project_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic NotGonnaShareThatNowAmI')
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($curl_response){
        $decoded = json_decode($curl_response, true);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($decoded as $key=>$value){
            // Eliminates Empty Fields and Saves to Multi-Dimensional Array
            if ($value){
                $value = id_mask($value);
            }
            switch($key)
            {
                case "PROJECT_NAME":
                    $key = null;
                    $html_tag = "h1";
                    break;
                case "STATUS":
                    $key = "Status";
                    $html_tag = "li";
                    break;
                case "PROJECT_DETAILS":
                    $key = "Description";
                    $html_tag = "li";
                    break;
                case "RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID":
                    $key = "Project Manager";
                    $html_tag = "li";
                    break;
                case "CATEGORY_ID":
                    $key = "Category";
                    $html_tag = "li";
                    break;
                default:
                    $value = null;
            }
            if ($value){
                $field = [$key, $value, $html_tag, $html_class, $html_id];
                $project[$i] = $field;
                $i++;
            }
        }

        return $project;
    }
    else {
        die('An error occurred retrieving Projects. Additional info: ' . curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
}

public function getActiveTasks($user_id){

    $project_tasks = getTasks($user_id);
    $tasks = loopAndFind($project_tasks, 'STATUS', 'IN PROGRESS');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($tasks as $key=>$value){
        $active_tasks[$i] = taskStyler($key, $value);
        $i++;
    }

    return $active_tasks;
}

public function getCompletedTasks($user_id){

    $project_tasks = getTasks($user_id);
    $tasks = loopAndFind($project_tasks, 'STATUS', 'COMPLETED');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($tasks as $key=>$value){
        $completed_tasks[$i] = taskStyler($key, $value);
        $i++;
    }
    return $completed_tasks;
}

function getTasks($user_id){

    $task_url = 'https://api.insight.ly/v2/tasks';

    $curl = curl_init($task_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic NotGonnaShareThatNowAmI')
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($curl_response){
        $decoded = json_decode($curl_response, true);
        $project_tasks = loopAndFind($decoded, 'PROJECT_ID', $user_id);
        return $project_tasks;
    }
    else {
        die('An Error occurred retrieving Tasks. Additional info: ' . curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
}

//Search Tool for Multi-Dimensional Arrays
function loopAndFind($array, $index, $search){
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        if($v[$index] == $search){
            $returnArray[] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $returnArray;
}

//Formats dates as d/m/Y and removes the time
function date_formatter($value){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $date = date_create($value);
    $value = date_format($date, "m/d/Y");
    return $value;
}

//Returns array with ALLCAPS corrected and html tags
function taskStyler ($key, $value){
    $html_tag = "li";
    $html_class = null;
    $html_id = null;

    switch ($key)
    {
        case "Title":
            $key = "Task";
            $html_tag = "h3";
            break;
        case "DUE_DATE":
            $key = "Due Date";
            $value = date_formatter($value);
            break;
        case "COMPLETED_DATE_UTC":
            $key = "Date Completed";
            $value = date_formatter($value);
            break;
        case "DETAILS":
            $key = "Details";
            $value = strip_tags($value);
            break;
        case "STATUS":
            $key = "Status";
            break;
        case "PERCENT_COMPLETE":
            $key = "Percent Complete";
            $value = $value . "&#37;";
            break;
        case "START_DATE":
            $key = "Start Date";
            $value = date_formatter($value);
            break;
        case "RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID":
            $key = "Assigned to";
            $value = id_mask($value);
            break;
        default:
            $value = null;
    }
    if ($value){
        $task = [$key, $value, $html_tag, $html_class, $html_id];
    }
    else {
        $task = null;
    }
    return $task;
}
}
```

site\views\insightly\view.html.php

```
// import Joomla view library
jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

/**
* HTML View class for the Insightly Component
*/

class InsightlyViewInsightly extends JViewLegacy
{

// Overwriting JView display method
function display($tpl = null)
{
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $user_id = $user->get( 'id' );
    $user_id= "765727";     //Set for Development

    // Assign data to the view
    $this->project = getProject($user_id);
    $this->active_tasks = getActiveTasks($user_id);
    $this->completed_tasks = getCompletedTasks($user_id);


    parent::display($tpl);
}
}
```

controller.php (which is empty)

```
// import Joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

/**
* Insightly Component Controller
*/
class InsightlyController extends JControllerLegacy
{
}
```

site\insightly.php

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// import joomla controller library
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

// Get an instance of the controller prefixed by Insightly
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('Insightly');

// Perform the Request task
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$controller->execute($input->getCmd('task'));

// Redirect if set by the controller
$controller->redirect();
```

site\views\insightly\tmpl\default.php

```
<article id='project'>
<?php
$iterations = count($this->project);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $iterations; $i++) {
    echo('<' . $this->project[2]);
    if (isset($this->project[3])) {
        echo('class ="' . $this->project[3]);
    }
    if (isset($this->project[4])) {
        echo('class ="' . $this->project[4]);
    }
    echo('>');
    echo($this->project[0]);
    echo(' : ');
    echo($this->project[1]);
    echo('</' . $this->project[2] . '>');
}

?>
<div id='tasks'>
    <h2>Active Tasks</h2>
    <section class='tasks'>
        <?php
        $number_of_tasks = count($this->active_tasks);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $number_of_tasks; $i++) {
            $task_iterations = count($this->active_tasks[$i]);
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $task_iterations; $i++) {
                echo('<' . $this->active_tasks[$i][2]);
                if (isset($this->active_tasks[$i][3])) {
                    echo('class ="' . $this->active_tasks[$i][3]);
                }
                if (isset($this->active_tasks[$i][4])) {
                    echo('class ="' . $this->active_tasks[$i][4]);
                }
                echo('>');
                echo($this->active_tasks[$i][0]);
                echo(' : ');
                echo($this->active_tasks[$i][1]);
                echo('</' . $this->active_tasks[$i][2] . '>');
            }
        }
        ?>
    </section>
    <h2>Completed Tasks</h2>
    <section class='tasks'>
        <?php
        $number_of_tasks = count($this->completed_tasks);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $number_of_tasks; $i++) {
            $task_iterations = count($this->completed_tasks[$i]);
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $task_iterations; $i++) {
                echo('<' . $this->completed_tasks[$i][2]);
                if (isset($this->completed_tasks[$i][3])) {
                    echo('class ="' . $this->completed_tasks[$i][3]);
                }
                if (isset($this->completed_tasks[$i][4])) {
                    echo('class ="' . $this->completed_tasks[$i][4]);
                }
                echo('>');
                echo($this->completed_tasks[$i][0]);
                echo(' : ');
                echo($this->completed_tasks[$i][1]);
                echo('</' . $this->completed_tasks[$i][2] . '>');
            }
        }
        ?>
    </section>
</div>
</article>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".tasks").accordion({ collapsible: true, active: false });
    });
</script>
```

Any insight on why I cant get to my models function? Also I welcome the pointing out of any  other blaring mistakes and security flaws.

EDIT: the idMask function was removed in my post due to sensitive content. It is probably not the issue.

EDIT: I have the component loading now and have updated the code but I'm having trouble with the arrays. `taskStyler` should return an array to be set to `$completed_tasks[i]`.

`completed_tasks[0][0]` is correct but `completed_tasks[0][1]` contains an array composed of what should be`completed_tasks[0][1-12]`.

This is my current version of the relevant functions:

Calls `getTasks` and compiles array of tasks that are in progress

```
public function getActiveTasks($user_id){

    $project_tasks = $this->getTasks($user_id);
    $tasks = $this->loopAndFind($project_tasks, 'STATUS', 'IN PROGRESS');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($tasks as $key=>$value){
            $active_tasks[$i] = $this->taskStyler($key, $value);
            $i++;
    }
    return $active_tasks;
}
```

Calls `getTasks` and compiles array of tasks that are completed

```
public function getCompletedTasks($user_id){

    $project_tasks = $this->getTasks($user_id);
    $tasks = $this->loopAndFind($project_tasks, 'STATUS', 'COMPLETED');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($tasks as $key=>$value){
            $completed_tasks[$i] = $this->taskStyler($key, $value);
            $i++;
    }
    return $completed_tasks;
}
```

Curl session with API server that returns an array of tasks (known to work perfectly)

```
public function getTasks($user_id){

    $task_url = 'https://api.insight.ly/v2/tasks';

    $curl = curl_init($task_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic Dontlookatmypassword')
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($curl_response){
        $decoded = json_decode($curl_response, true);
        $project_tasks = $this->loopAndFind($decoded, 'PROJECT_ID', $user_id);
        return $project_tasks;
    }
    else {
        die('An Error occurred retrieving Tasks. Additional info: ' . curl_error($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Returns an array representing a datafield of a task with the keys and some values edited for readability, and html tags, classes and ids appended.

```
public function taskStyler ($key, $value){
    $html_tag = "li";
    $html_class = null;
    $html_id = null;

    switch ($key)
    {
        case "Title":
            $key = "Task";
            $html_tag = "h3";
            break;
        case "DUE_DATE":
            $key = "Due Date";
            $value = $this->dateFormatter($value);
            break;
        case "COMPLETED_DATE_UTC":
            $key = "Date Completed";
            $value = $this->dateFormatter($value);
            break;
        case "DETAILS":
            $key = "Details";
            $value = strip_tags($value);
            break;
        case "STATUS":
            $key = "Status";
            break;
        case "PERCENT_COMPLETE":
            $key = "Percent Complete";
            $value = $value . "&#37;";
            break;
        case "START_DATE":
            $key = "Start Date";
            $value = $this->dateFormatter($value);
            break;
        case "RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID":
            $key = "Assigned to";
            $value = $this->idMask($value);
            break;
        default:
            $value = null;
    }
    if ($value) {
        $task = [$key, $value, $html_tag, $html_class, $html_id];
    }
    else{ $task = null;
    }
    return $task;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your view.

You can use `$this->get('project')`, which would call the `getProject()` method of your model. However it doesn't allow to pass an argument.

Thus in your case, you need to fetch the model first and the call the method on it:

```
$model   = $this->getModel();
$project = $model->getProject($user_id);
```

Comment: I was also missing a $this->  in front of EVERY function call in the method and view.

-Thank you.

Comment: @WishingWellIndustries you should accept Bakual's answer then

Comment: I ended up creating a function in the model to get the user id, calling that within each get*Task function and getting the returned variable in the view. Keeps the view honest.

Answer (score 0):

To pass params to your model functions add the below to your view display task

> $model = $this->getModel();

Then prefix getProject() and the others with

> $model->

Then you can pass params to the methods.

Happy Joomla!ng

Comment: Basically what @Bukual said.

Comment: Yep. I answered before I saw that part of his answer. Should have scrolled with Stackexchange mobile app.